# Describing the plane curve $α(θ)$ that has the following property: the area of the triangle given by $cQT$ is constant (details below)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

A plane curve, $α(θ)$, has the following property: if $c(θ)$ is the center of curvature of $α$ in $θ$, $Q(θ)$ is the projection of $α(θ)$ on the x axis and $T(θ)$ is the intersection point of the tangent line to $α$ in $θ$ with the x axis, then the area of the triangle $cQT$ is constant. Give the parametrization for the curve $α(θ)$, where the parameter $θ$ is the angle between the tangent to $α(θ)$ and the x axis.

I know $c(θ) = α(θ) + \frac{n(θ)}{k(θ)}$, and $Q(θ) = (x(θ), 0)$ (given that $α(θ) = (x(θ),y(θ))$, but I haven't been able to put all the other information together. I know I should find an expression for $T(θ)$ as well, but I'm having trouble with that too. I've been stuck on this for a while, so I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

**EDIT:** After over a year with no progress to this question, I'm giving it a bounty. It's eating away at me that I haven't been able to solve such a basic problem.

Comment: I've thought about this for ten minutes or so. It does not look like an appealing problem to me. But I will tell you that $n(\theta) = (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$. The distance from $T$ to $Q$ is not so bad — it's $y(\theta)\cot\theta$. You don't need $T$ and $Q$ individually.

Comment: How did you come to those results?

Comment: The last sentence in the first paragraph :) The unit tangent vector to the curve is $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. And, for the distance, just look at the right triangle with vertices $T$, $Q$, and $\alpha(\theta)$. But the problem appears totally yucky. Where did you find it? (The other differential geometry problems you've asked on this site are totally standard ones.)

Comment: I found it going through Keti Tenenblat's "Introduction to differential geometry". Yeah, a lot of the problems there can be yucky like that but the book does a good job of explaining things.

Comment: I know her, actually. Is her text using differential forms and moving frames? (Maybe you'll only notice that when you get to surfaces.)

Comment: It does use moving frames, but it takes a while to get to differential forms.

Comment: By the way, I just looked up who you are... and wow. So awesome to have someone like you answer my question.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't answered it much :) I'm not yet convinced that it's an interesting question, either. But it may turn out to be. ... Plenty of good problems in my differential geometry text, too :P At least I know how to do (most of) those :)

Comment: Huh. I knew your name looked familiar. I've been using your text, along with do Carmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces" for supplementary reading (although I haven't done as many problems). It is really good indeed!

Comment: Since $QT$ lies on the $x$ axis, an area of $cQT$ equals a half of a product of a distance between $QT$, (which is $y(\theta)\cot\theta$, according to Ted Shifrin’s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574257/describing-the-plane-curve-%ce%b1%ce%b8-that-has-the-following-property-the-area-of-t#comment5317243_2574257)) by an absolute value of the ordinate of the point $c$ (which is $y(\theta)+\tfrac{\cos\theta}{k(\theta)}$), and I guess that $\tfrac{1}{k(\theta)}=\tfrac{|x’y’’-y’x’’|}{(x’^2+y’^2)^{3/2}},$ where the derivatives are taken with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: Also maybe the condition that $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent to $\alpha(\theta)$ and the $x$ axis allows to simplify an expression for $k(\theta)$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I've tried to do that, but believe me, it really doesn't... the resulting systems of differential equations get pretty ugly pretty fast.